# REST API: Using a GET Request to match an ID within a File and display the object corresponding to ID

Tags: java, rest, restful-url

I really need help with a RESTful API project that I am working on. I have done extensive searches and am at a crossroad. This is very new to me and I am not quite understanding everything, so I do apologize if this is an elementary question.

**What I am required to do:**

I am required to create a "getVehicle" method that will do the following:

- getVehicle() will take a given id, and find the vehicle that has the
  matching id.
- It will iterate the local file line-by-line, check if
  the id matches, and if there is a match return the vehicle object.

**This is the header:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getVehicle/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Vehicle getVehicle(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException {
```

I do know how to do this using purely Java, but this RESTful stuff is throwing me for a loop.

**My understanding:**

For what I understand is that, when I make my GET request (I use Advance REST Client for this), the ID that I input for {id} will be matched to what is within my text file (called inventory.txt).

I have populated my text file with 6 entries using my POST method, all of which are information about various "vehicles". Therefore, if I make a GET request to url http://localhost808/getVehicle/2, I should get information about the "vehicle" with id 2.

**My problem:**

However, with what I currently have, my file is not being iterated, so the only "vehicle" that I get is id 0.

**What I have so far:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getVehicle/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Vehicle getVehicle(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException 
    {
        //ObjectMapper provides functionality for reading and writing JSON
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String inventory = FileUtils.readFileToString(new 
            File("./inventory.txt"),
                CharEncoding.UTF_8);

        //Deserialize JSON to vehicle object
        Vehicle vehicle = mapper.readValue(inventory, Vehicle.class);

        if (vehicle.getId() == id) {
                return vehicle;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**My Request:**

I am at a lost on how to iterate through my text file to find the id that is being requested.

Figuring out this one thing will drastically clear up my confusing and help me reach the completion of my project

ANY hints, tips, resources, anything that will put me on the path of figuring this out will be GREATLY appreciated. Again, this is very nice to me and I am trying to keep my sanity here.

**If I need to clarify anything, please let me know!**

I give thanks to anyone and everyone who takes the time to help me out here :D!

Comment: What I don't see is an iteration loop of any kind. I'm assuming `vehicle` return an object, you need to iterate through that using something like `for (v: vehicle) { if statement}`.

Comment: I tried that and I got an error that said: "foreach not applicable to type 'com.example.Vehicle'". I am assuming that I cannot use foreach with my object type??

Comment: Did you give it what type of variable `v` going to be? Sorry, I forgot to add this `for (Vehicle v: vehicle) { System.out.println(v); }`. See if this works.

Comment: Yes, I did that. "vehicle" is underlined, with the error I mentioned previously. Does my package path have something to do with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved using LineIterator!

My code is here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getVehicle/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Vehicle getVehicle(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException {

    //ObjectMapper provides functionality for reading and writing JSON
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //Makes inventory.txt an iterable object
    LineIterator inventory = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File("./inventory.txt"),
            CharEncoding.UTF_8);

    //Container for when vehicle is found
    String vehicle = "";

    //iterates through inventory.txt until it reaches the end or finds the vehicle via id
    while(inventory.hasNext()) { 
        //Stores each vehicle
        String tempVehicle = inventory.next(); 
        //Creates a vehicle object for JSON
        Vehicle v = mapper.readValue(tempVehicle, Vehicle.class); 

        //checks if id of JSON vehicle object matches the id passed through
        if(v.getId() == id) { 
            vehicle = tempVehicle;
        }
    }
    //Returns the found vehicle as a new Objectmapper (still a bit confused about this one)
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(vehicle, Vehicle.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate through the `inventory` because it's a string. You can iterate through `vehicle` since you're converting the `inventory` string to Vehicle objects.

Ok So there is a bug I just realised. `Vehicle vehicle` this is a single object. You need an array.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getVehicle/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                 produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Vehicle getVehicle(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException {
    //ObjectMapper provides functionality for reading and writing JSON
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String inventory = FileUtils.readFileToString(new 
        File("./inventory.txt"),
            CharEncoding.UTF_8);

    //Deserialize JSON to vehicle object
    List<Vehicle> vehicle = (Vehicle)mapper.readValue(inventory, Vehicle.class);
    // Or
    List<Object> vehicle = mapper.readValue(inventory, Vehicle.class);
    // Recommend the first option, its better to use types, things less likely to go wrong.

    for (Vehicle v: vehicle){
      if (vehicle.getId() == id) {
        return vehicle;
      }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: That was why you always get Object 0 no matter what ID you've passed. It mapped the first one and discarded the rest.

Comment: I tried this and now I get a new error for mapper.readValue(inventory, Vehicle.class). I strongly agree that I need an iterative loop and I know that it has to deal with "vehicle" but I am at a lost on the structure needed for it to iterate through it. I am thinking that I need to populate a List with my vehicle entries, but, again, how do I go about this?

Comment: Error: "  Incompatible types. Required List<Vehicle> but 'readValue' was inferred to T: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Vehicle conforms to List<Vehicle> inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Vehicle upper bounds: Object, List<Vehicle>  "

Comment: Ok, so it's complaining that you're trying to map values with no type `Object` to a variable with type `Vehicle`. You can either create `List<Object>` or cast the `Object` to `Vehicle` type. I'll update the answer. Also, do you have a Git repo that I can take a look at? Its lot easier to fix something with hands-on.

Comment: I got it solved. A friend suggested using LineInterator instead of what I was doing with String inventory. This way was much better and understandable. Thank you very much for your help!!!